# Java, servlet, JSP, FrontController: How to create a dynamic table to show each ArrayList's item as a row?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

**Hello and thank you for your help!**

I am currently learning how to use servlets and JSP players to implement FrontController pattern.

First I will show the behaviour I would like to fix, then the code, and then the questions.

I have created 9 courses using a form, and it only shows the last one, and the other 8 are null, I added the current iteration count to debbug if it was iterating well:
[image]

My FrontServlet which is the main web app's entry point:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org;

import frontController.FrontCommand;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author YonePC
 */
@WebServlet(name = "FrontServlet", urlPatterns = {"/FrontServlet"})
public class FrontServlet extends HttpServlet {

    ArrayList cursos = new ArrayList();

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            Curso curso = (Curso) session.getAttribute("curso");
            if (curso != null) {
                cursos.add(curso);
                session.setAttribute("cursos",cursos);
            } else {
                curso = new Curso(request.getParameter("titulo"),
                        request.getParameter("autor"),
                        request.getParameter("asignatura"),
                        request.getParameter("duracion"),
                        request.getParameter("video"));
                cursos.add(curso);
                session.setAttribute("cursos",cursos);
            }

            FrontCommand command = getCommand(request);
            command.init(getServletContext(), request, response);
            command.process(request);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FrontServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    private FrontCommand getCommand(HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
        try {
            FrontCommand f = (FrontCommand) getCommandClass(req).newInstance();
            return f;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

    }

    private Class getCommandClass(HttpServletRequest req) {
        Class result;
        final String command = "frontController." + (String) req.getParameter("command");
        try {
            result = Class.forName(command);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            result = UnknownCommand.class;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

The abstract class FrontCommand which is the boilerplate for concrete commands:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package frontController;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author YonePC
 */
public abstract class FrontCommand {

    protected ServletContext context;
    protected HttpServletRequest request;
    protected HttpServletResponse response;

    public void init(ServletContext context, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.context = context;
        this.request = request;
        this.response = response;
    }

    abstract public void process(HttpServletRequest request);

    public void forward(String target) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dp = context.getRequestDispatcher(target);
        dp.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

The command being called by FrontServlet when we submit the form related to course's creation:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package frontController;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.Curso;

/**
 *
 * @author YonePC
 */
@WebServlet(name = "CourseInfoCommand", urlPatterns = {"/CourseInfoCommand"})
public class CourseInfoCommand extends FrontCommand {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

    @Override
    public void process(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        ArrayList cursos = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("cursos");

        if (cursos != null) {
            Iterator i = cursos.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                int current = 0;
                Curso cursoActual = (Curso) i.next();

                request.setAttribute("titulo" + current, cursoActual.getTitulo());
                request.setAttribute("autor" + current, cursoActual.getAutor());
                request.setAttribute("asignatura" + current, cursoActual.getAsignatura());
                request.setAttribute("duracion" + current, cursoActual.getDuracion());
                request.setAttribute("video" + current, cursoActual.getVideo());

                current++;
            }
        }
        try {
            forward("/CourseInfo.jsp");
        } catch (ServletException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CourseInfoCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CourseInfoCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

And the CourseInfo.jsp file where we collect and show the data:

```
<%@page import="org.Curso"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<html> 
    <body> 
        <table width="100%" border=1>
            <tr>
                <th style="padding: 8px">Titulo</th>
                <th style="padding: 8px">Autor</th>
                <th style="padding: 8px">Asignatura</th>
                <th style="padding: 8px">Duracion</th>
                <th style="padding: 8px">Video</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%= request.getAttribute("titulo")%></td>
                <td><%= request.getAttribute("autor")%></td>
                <td><%= request.getAttribute("asignatura")%></td>
                <td><%= request.getAttribute("duracion")%></td>
                <td><a href="<%= request.getAttribute("video")%>">Video</a></td>
            </tr>

            <% if (session.getAttribute("cursos") != null) {%>
            <tr>
                <% ArrayList cursos = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("cursos");
                    Iterator i = cursos.iterator();
                    int current = 0;
                    while (i.hasNext()) {
                        Curso cursoActual = (Curso) i.next();
                %>
                <td><%= request.getAttribute("titulo" + current)%></td>
                <td><%= request.getAttribute("autor" + current)%></td>
                <td><%= request.getAttribute("asignatura" + current)%></td>
                <td><%= request.getAttribute("duracion" + current)%></td>
                <td><a href="<%= request.getAttribute("video" + current)%>">Video</a></td>
                <%
                    current++;
                %>
            <br/>
            <p>current: <%= current%></p>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </tr>
        <br/>
        <% }%>
    </table>
</body> 
</html>
```

I first though that the problem could be because of I have included:

```
ArrayList cursos = new ArrayList(); in FrontServlet creation.
```

But then I realized that servlets are supposed to be shared between clients so it is not being recreated.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that in CourseInfoCommand, the concreteCommand I should initialize the current counter before the while loop:

```
if (cursos != null) {
            Iterator i = cursos.iterator();
            int current = 0;
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                Curso cursoActual = (Curso) i.next();

                request.setAttribute("titulo" + current, cursoActual.getTitulo());
                request.setAttribute("autor" + current, cursoActual.getAutor());
                request.setAttribute("asignatura" + current, cursoActual.getAsignatura());
                request.setAttribute("duracion" + current, cursoActual.getDuracion());
                request.setAttribute("video" + current, cursoActual.getVideo());

                current++;
            }
        }
```

So thanks to post the previous question I realized the bug